# PHP sum up all EVEN numbers from 0 to 200

Tags: php

I tried to sum up all even numbers from 0 to 200 and I found 2 possible working ways, however the third method (the most efficient one) gives me a headache. Here's what I did so far:

First method:

```
$total = 0;
$number = 0;

while ($number < 200)
{
    if ($number % 2 == 0)
    {
        $total = $total + $number;
    }
    $number++;
}

echo $total;
```

Second method:

```
    $total = 0;
    for($number = 0; $number < 200; $number+=2) 
    {
        $total += $number;
    }
echo $total;
```

Third method (can't get it to work)

```
echo array_sum(range(1,200,2));
```

How should I change my last method so that it works as intended?

Edit: Seems that none of the methods work: the output should be 10100 but it is 9900 for the first two methods and 10000 for the third.

Comment: What is the output / error of third method?

Comment: The third method outputs 10000 as opposed to the 9900 (the correct answer). Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
echo array_sum(range(0,198,2));
```

or

```
echo array_sum(range(0,199,2));
```

> **Its because the above function will sum up the values upto `200` whereas within your `while` and `for` loop will count upto `198` only as you have specifically defined**

```
$number < 200
```

Comment: Indeed, and I should write $number <= 200. Thank you very much. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

begin from 0 but 1

```
echo array_sum(range(0,200,2));
```

result 10100

Comment: No, the output is indeed correct, it's 10100. It seems that the first two methods are not working thou, edited my question to point that out. The output is 9900 and it seems that it should be 10100.

Comment: @MateiPanchios that's why I've posted the output too

Answer (score 1):

In the two methods that you tried, you have a condition that the number should not exceed more than 200. I also used the same scenario here.

```
echo array_sum(range(0,199,2));
```

Gives the expected output of 9900.

But the Correct answer is 10100.

To get 10100, We need to replace 199 with 200.

The formula (Mathematically)

> 2+4+6+8+10+..............+198+200 = 2(1+2+3+4+5+.....+100)
>
> = 2 ((100*101)/2)  (Formula: n(n+1)/2; n is the last term)
>
> = 100*101
>
> = 10100